# Simple mod_rewrite example

Tags: python, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to write a simple mod_rewrite rule, and I have no clue as to why it's not working.

I simply want to rewrite `http://example.com/to/abc` to `http://example.com/to/index.py?to=abc`.

Currently, my rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?to/(.*)$ /to/index.py?to=$1
```

Which, to my knowledge, should match any URL similar to `/to/whatever`, with or without the leading `/`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Any chance this is a configuration issue?

Comment: I don't get any errors in the logs. I simply get a 404 error saying that /to/whatever doesn't exist.

Comment: It seems like the rule should be fine -- I even ran it through an rewrite rule tester, so the next likely thing would seem to be a config issue. Are other rules working? Is this in a .htaccess file and if so, are they turned on?

Comment: This is in a .htaccess file. They are definitely turned on, because they are working elsewhere. This particular one is working, because I have other working directives in it. I tried a few other rewrite rules to test, and some seemed to work

Comment: This should redirect /to/test to /to/index.py?to=test, correct?

Comment: I tried it out here http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ and it does seem like it should be doing that yes. If you put these two lines in the file, and nothing else, does it work? Maybe something else is interfering.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you haven't mentioned in what way, exactly, it's "not working". If I had to guess, I would say that it's probably looping, and you need to do this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.py
RewriteRule ^/?to/(.*)$ /to/index.py?to=$1 [PT]
```

That says "don't rewrite it if it's already been rewritten.

The [PT] on there also says "treat this target as a URI, rather than as a file path.

However, in order to be certain, you'll need to tell us what's happening, and in what way it differs from what you want to be happening. Error log entries would be helpful. Rewrite log entries would be even more helpful.